# Can anyone help me in these questions (related to Work Done)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

1. Can work done by *Kinetic Friction* on an object be positive? Zero?
2. Can *Static Friction* do Non-zero work on an object?
3. Can *Normal Force* do Non-zero work on an object?

Comment: How would the person who voted to close this because it needs "more focus" propose to add more focus? Splitting it into three separate questions seems pointless. Apart from that, what else could be done to improve it?

Comment: but 3 people helped me so no issue , People those who love physics are there to help

Comment: @alephzero Perhaps the OP could ask about what they do not understand about how forces do work that is preventing them from answering the questions, thus making this into a single question. The OP could additionally include what they think about these points; why they think these forces can / cannot do work, why they are unsure, etc.

Comment: We already know you are wanting help with a question. The title should be a specific indicator of what your question relates to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can work done by Kinetic Friction on an object be positive? Zero?

Yes for both questions,

[image]

In this case block [a7] is moves in the indicated direction, The block [h] Initially at rest moves in the direction of block [a7] due to kinetic friction that acts in the same direction as block [a7] moves

To an observer on the ground, it will seem like work done is positive.

It can also be zero a good example is given by dale in the comments.

> Can Static Friction do Non-zero work on an object?

In this case, let block [a7] be slow enough that there is no relative slipping between the two blocks.Here static friction acts and it will be positive in the ground frame

> Can Normal Force do Non-zero work on an object?

Also yes, let's say I have a plate and a mango on it, I move the plate up the normal force moves it a distance up thus doing work

Comment: For part 1, the work done by kinetic friction on an object can indeed be zero. All that is required is that the object be stationary. Consider a book sliding across a heavy table with the table remaining stationary.

Comment: @Dale Yep thanks, Cleaned up the post. Did I make any more of such blunders?

Comment: That was all I saw. +1 on the revised answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Can work done by Kinetic Friction on an object be positive? Zero?

Yes it can be either positive or negative or zero for an object. But always negative for a system.

> Can Static Friction do Non-zero work on an object?

Yes. Consider the following example :

A cart of mass $m_1$ has a block of mass $m_2$ on top of it.

The co-efficient of friction between the two bodies is $\mu$

If the cart is moving with constant velocity and the block of mass $m_2$ is stationary relative to the cart, then you can see that the work done by static friction is positive on the block of mass $m_2$

> Can Normal Force do Non-zero work on an object?

Yes of course, why not ?
Consider the following example :

Suppose there is a block in an elevator which is moving upward with constant velocity, then you can see that the work done by the normal force on the block is positive, from the ground frame and which is equal and opposite to work done by gravity.

Answer (score 0):

In each case you need to consider the scalar product (dot product) of the force and the velocity of the object to which the force is applied.

Does the force have a positive component in the same direction as the object’s velocity ? If so, it is doing positive work on the object i.e. increasing the object’s energy.

Does the force have a positive component in the opposite direction to the object’s velocity ? If so, it is doing negative work on the object i.e. decreasing the object’s energy.

Comment: okay, but what about an inclined plane , now what will be work done for _Normal Force_ in that case

Comment: @HitmanA7 find the displacement then dot product with force i.e. fdcosthetha,